# Map values to javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache-flex, actionscript-3

http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php In the following link .Is it possible to get the upload /download limit which is displayed on the screen to a javascript alert(uploadlimit) or alert(downloadlimit)

Comment: Do you means extract the content in http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php? Or, you want to know how to connect flash and js?

Comment: How can i upload a file on SO?I have this working but how will i alert the values

Comment: You can't.  You can link to a free file sharing site, though.

Answer (score 0):

From AS3 to JS:

AS3

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternallInterface.call("alert", uploadlimit);
}
```

You may also replace "alert" by any custom available function.

---

And from JS to AS3:

JS

```
 function thisMovie(movieName) {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
     } else {
         return document[movieName];
     }
 }
 function sendToActionScript(value) {
     thisMovie("ExternalInterfaceExample").sendToActionScript(value);
 }
```

AS3

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionScript", receivedFromJavaScript);
}
```

Then you only have to create an AS3 method called `receivedFromJavaScript`, the parameters given in JS will fly magically to your AS3 method.

Comment: Is it possible to call a Button in flex/AS3 from javascript.i.e,On click of a javascript variable invoke some button in fles/AS#,if so please point me to some example.Thanks..